# Adding not-yet-saved objects to MappedManyToMany

Tags: scala, many-to-many, lift, mapper

The project I am working on has run into some undesirable Mapper behaviour.  It seems you cannot add objects to many-to-many associations unless the objects are already saved in the database (more specifically, you cannot retrieve some not-saved objects from many-to-many associations).

As an example we have Employees and Departments in an M:N relationship.  We instantiate 2 departments: Accounting and Security.  Accounting gets employees before they are saved, Security gets employees after they are saved.

```scala
object Employee extends Employee with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Employee]
class Employee extends LongKeyedMapper[Employee] with IdPK {
  def getSingleton = Employee
  object name extends MappedString(this, 20)
  override def toString = name.get
}

object Department extends Department with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Department]
class Department extends LongKeyedMapper[Department] with ManyToMany with IdPK {
  def getSingleton = Department
  object employees extends MappedManyToMany(
    EmployeeDepartment,
    EmployeeDepartment.department,
    EmployeeDepartment.employee,
    Employee)
}

/* Many-to-Many association record */
object EmployeeDepartment extends EmployeeDepartment with LongKeyedMetaMapper[EmployeeDepartment]
class EmployeeDepartment extends LongKeyedMapper[EmployeeDepartment] with IdPK {
  def getSingleton = EmployeeDepartment

  object employee extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, Employee)
  object department extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, Department)
}

object Company extends App {
  DB.defineConnectionManager(DefaultConnectionIdentifier, myDBVendor)

  val accounting = Department.create
  val security = Department.create

  accounting.employees ++= Seq(
    Employee.create.name("Fred"),
    Employee.create.name("Steve"))

  security.employees ++= Seq(
    Employee.create.name("Dave"),
    Employee.create.name("Sonia")) map
    {_.saveMe()}

  accounting.employees.toList map println; println
  security.employees.toList map println
}
```

### Output

```
Fred
Fred

Dave
Sonia
```

!!!

The employees of accounting have all turned into Fred!  The problem scales similarly: adding 10 not-yet-saved entities to `accounting.employees` yields 10 references to Fred on access.

This appears to either be a bug, or a serious limitation to the usefulness of Mapper.  Is there a workaround for this behaviour that does not involve either:

- using some data structure external to the model to keep track of entities and associations until you are ready to save, or
- saving entities on create, issuing deletes if the user "changes their mind" about saving

Comment: Just out of interest, are you using Lift Mapper as a library to do your ORM, or are you using the whole Lift framework? If it's the latter, you may want to have a look at Slick.

Comment: We are using Mapper as part of the Lift framework.  At this point in the project going to [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/0.11.2/index.html) would be somewhat expensive as much of the application is written.  Also, we leverage html generation and validation features of Mapper (which I don't think Slick has).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the concrete reason  for this apparent misbehaviour.  Adding elements to a many-to-many association invokes the following algorithm:

```
Find "other" element in "this" join list.
if not found
  create join and add to join list
else
  add to join list
```

The rub is in the find criteria.  Specified in ManyToMany.scala (Lift 2.4), method `isJoinForChild` compares the [`is`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.mapper.MappedField) of the association foreign key (`MappedManyToMany` constructor parameter 3) with the primary key (also `is`) of the "other" element.

As every non-saved entity `with IdPK` has id=-1, the first element in the "this" join list satisfies the find criteria and is then added in duplicate.

This answers my original question: it is possible to fix this behaviour by modifying `isJoinForChild`.  Rather than simply comparing keys, the method would do something akin to:

```
if other.is > -1
  regular comparison
else
  instance comparison
```

... or something to that effect.  Since `isJoinForChild` is `protected` this can be accomplished non-invasively by overriding `isJoinForChild` using a trait.